# Tabbed Content on Product Pages in prestashop

Tags: e-commerce, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I've been trying to change the new 1.6 product.tpl to use tabbed content (similar to the default 1.5 theme), so that 'More Info', 'Data Sheet', 'Volume Discounts' etc each appears with a clickable tab that reveals the content.

I'm not sure why this wasn't included? Would it mess up the responsiveness of the theme?

I'm currently completely stuck as to how to code this - can anyone give me any pointers on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I successfully applied the solution pointed out in this blog post on a 1.6.0.7 Prestashop installation:

http://mypresta.eu/en/art/prestashop-16/product-tabs.html

Works like a charm on default theme.